# Is there any way of using EmguCV with Unity for UWP (HoloLens) app development without buying EmguCV package from Unity asset store?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, uwp, emgucv, hololens

I am developing a face detection app for my HoloLens for testing purpose. For this, I am using Unity and OpenCv wrapper library EmguCv. I have developed similar desktop applications using EmguCv and Unity. But, now I want to develop some for HoloLens. I have tried almost every way of using EmguCv for Hololens with Unity but I failed to deploy those on the HoloLens. Cuz whenever I select "Release" solution configuration for deploying Visual studio show error of not identifying the EmguCv DLLs.

Now, the EmguCv package in the Unity store is around $400 and I don't want to spend that amount of money. So, kindly suggest me some (easy) way, if there is one, for using EmguCv for HoloLens development through Unity.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have those DLLs somewhere? It sounds like in the editor it works and only building fails? afaik you have to copy the dlls into the Unity build before building and deploying in VS

Comment: EmguCv DLLs can only be added after building the application. And I can't run the the application form the editor as I don't have the EmguCv package. The only way to test, is to deploy the app. I think these DLLs does'nt support UWP developement.

Comment: EmguCv should work for UWP, they support Windows Phone.  does the UWP [sample](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/RealtimeCamera.UWP) build for hololens OK?  I'm not sure about the differences between supporting UWP and supporting Hololens UWP..

Comment: Well, I don't know about other UWPs but, it is not working for HoloLens. I have searched alot on this matter and mostly people are telling to write my own DLL or to buy the package from unity store.. And yet I am still trying to find a way to make it work on HoloLens..